# How can input be provided to a PowerShell script within a CA Nimsoft PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I utilize the CA Nimsoft tool to deploy PowerShell scripts to computers with agents installed. Currently, I execute the following Nimsoft script to log into another computer and deploy a script.

NIMSOFT script

```
    param($TARGET="sw02111", $ProfileName="CustoPowerShell", $SCRIPT="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Users\Desktop\Desktop\b.ps1'")


$HubRobotListPath = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\hubrobots.txt"
$UserName = "administrator"
$Password = "Password@123"
$Domain = "DomainA"
$HubOne ="sw02111"
```

Now, I have a script named b.ps1, and it requires input through Read-Host. How can I pass input from the Nimsoft script to b.ps1?

Content of b.ps1 script:

```
$servicename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the Service Name'
Start-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction Stop
```

I aim to pass a value from the Nimsoft script to b.ps1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add into start PowerShell script this row :

```
Param( [string] $Param1)
```

and modify PowerShell code like this :

```
$servicename = $Param1
Start-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction Stop
```

into you nimsoft script modify like this :

```
param($TARGET="sw02111", $ProfileName="CustoPowerShell", $SCRIPT="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Users\H588753\Desktop\b.ps1' 'value of service you want'")
```